# JS: Your function is not a function! TypeError

Tags: javascript

I have a small RTS game where you can attack a monster. I want it setup that when the game loads or starts, the `strike()` function will trigger after 3 seconds. However when I run this code below, I get a type-error that "strike()" is not a function. If its not a function, *what is it then?*

If your wondering what `player.cc` means, it stands for current character. The rest is just referring to a balance meter I have in the game.

```
dom.el("strike").onclick = function strike() {
    HitCalc(player.cc, monster.cc);
    actor.expCounter(player.cc);
    actor.balanceCounter(player.cc, monster.cc);
};

 setTimeout(strike(), 3000);
```

Additional code that may help:

```
dom = {
    el: function (id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },
```

HTML:

```
<button id="strike" type="button" class="buttons">Strike</button>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(strike, 3000);`

Comment: I tried that and this happened:

SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
[object HTMLButtonElement]

Comment: @squint this is not really a duplicate, as something more interesting is happening there. Of course `setTimeout(strike(), 3000)` is obvious problem, but there is also incorrect usage of named function expression.

Comment: @user2763154 The code in the comment is definitely the correct code (if the function expression is rewritten to a function declaration). The subsequent syntax error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry but it's wrongly closed. The issue has nothing to do with the dup q&a..

Comment: @squint Please re-open this Q&A... I was about to finish my answer, and the issue has nothing to do with the dup...

Comment: `function strike() {
    HitCalc(player.cc, monster.cc);
    actor.expCounter(player.cc);
    actor.balanceCounter(player.cc, monster.cc);
};
dom.el("strike").onclick = strike;
 setTimeout(strike, 3000);`

Comment: @dfsq: Thanks, you're right. I missed the scope issue.

Comment: @PranavCBalan This is what I was going to answer when someone closed it and I've lost my text ARGH

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer : you can do it now  :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks!! ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you think that a function *with name* assigned to an event handler is still hoisted and declared in your current scope, you're mistaken on this part: it's still a function assigned to a property like any anonymous, inline function.

What you need is this:

```
function strike() {
    HitCalc(player.cc, monster.cc);
    actor.expCounter(player.cc);
    actor.balanceCounter(player.cc, monster.cc);
};

dom.el("strike").onclick = strike;

// Note that setTimeout expects a reference to the function rather than
// a function call!!
setTimeout(strike, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I was out of my scope which pretty much explains the issue. Thank you sir. :)

Comment: @user2763154 No problem! ;)